# how to center a navbar with homepage saving its color

Tags: html, css

When I zoom my page in and out it works, but homepage button loses its color, it doesn't expand to the right side.
So I have 2 aims:

1) To center selected area (on the picture allotted by red color).

2) To have homepage's green color expanded to the right to the end of the page.

Sorry for my English. Ask me if I didn't make the question clear.

[what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/que14.jpg)

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfqje.png)

[what makes me cry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Kyo.png)

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Infusion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="infusion.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul class="unlist">
        <a href="#"><li class="homepage"><p class="parhome">infusion</p></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="nav-elements">design folio</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="nav-elements">services</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="nav-elements">our business</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="nav-elements">how we help</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="nav-elements">take the tour</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="nav-elements">contact</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
  width: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.unlist {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.homepage {
  background-color: #63C6AE;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 360px;
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 75px;
}
.parhome {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.parhome:hover {
  color: #586165;
}
.unlist.a:first-child {
  width: 148px;
}
.nav-elements {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  height: 70px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 70px;

}
.unlist a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #63C6AE;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.inlist, a:hover {
  color: #586165;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid HTML to put a `p` tag into an `li` element. You can use a `span` instead.

Apart from that, you are limiting the width of your navbar with this CSS rule `.navbar { width: 2000px; [...] }`.

So when you zoom out, those 2000px (on a large monitor at full screen view) are less than what the window shows (zoomed!), therefore the green area's left border starts where those zoomed 2000px start.

You might want to change the navbar width setting to `100%`.

Comment: Totally correct, but shouldn't this be a comment, not an answer?

Comment: @Rüzgar I added something which should make it a "real" answer

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches can be used to achieve what you want. But all of these approaches that i can think of, need a little bit hack. Meaning, the solution that i am posting here is not an elegant way of handling things.

The reason for that, is what you aim consists of two things.

1. Center the navbar
2. Make the homepage container fill with green to all the way left.

Trying to solve both, creates some conflicts which are not easy to solve. And especially if you also want your page to be responsive.

Before start as @Johannes stated, your code consists of elements which are not valid, therefore i tried to change your code a little bit, as much as i could.

So here is my approach:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.cont {
    width: 1280px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 70px;
}
.unlist {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.homepage {
    background-color: #63C6AE;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 360px;
    height: 70px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -950px;
}
ul.homepage a {
    color: #fff;
}
.parhome {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.parhome:hover {
  color: #586165;
}
.unlist.a:first-child {
  width: 148px;
}
.nav-elements {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height: 70px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 70px;
}
.unlist a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #63C6AE;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.inlist, a:hover {
  color: #586165;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="cont">
  <ul class="homepage">
   <li class="nav-elements parhome"><a href="#">infusion</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="unlist">
   <li class="nav-elements"><a href="#">design folio</a></li>
   <li class="nav-elements"><a href="#">services</a></li>
   <li class="nav-elements"><a href="#">our business</a></li>
   <li class="nav-elements"><a href="#">how we help</a></li>
   <li class="nav-elements"><a href="#">take the tour</a></li>
   <li class="nav-elements"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

> **NOTE:** You can play with numbers, such as `margin-left` and `width` for exact results.